# Flutter Deployment Not Working With GitHub Pages

Tags: flutter, github, deployment, http-status-code-404, github-pages

I tried to deploy my portfolio to GitHub pages. But no images appear. I tried using both relative and absolute paths. But nothing seems to work. I am getting a 404 error for all the images. I will be really kind if the deployment process is explained a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One Line Answer** - Press `F12`, check for errors (404 errors). If images are not there at the location then manually add them there.

**Detailed process** -

So, Let me take this opportunity for explaining the complete process. Run the following commands from root directory -

`flutter channel`

if channel is not "stable" then -

`flutter channel stable`

After this -`flutter upgrade`

Then - `flutter clean`

Then - `flutter build web`

Now make a new repo in GitHub (let us call it 'Web'). Clone it to a suitable location. Copy files from root_directory/build/web to this newly cloned repo.

Now go open 'index.html' in a code editor and comment out the href base line.

Now push the changes to the repo 'Web'. Go to settings -> select master branch and click on save.

Open the website. If images don't appear then -

Press `F12`, check for errors (404 errors). If images are not there at the location then manually add them there.

**Another Way -**

instead of loading images from assets use site like 'imgur', CORS also has no problem here.